# Symfony3 regex access_control in security.yml

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I can not find the right regex to define a security rule for the following pattern:

http://example.com/**manager/?conf=xxxxx**

It is to be able to access different directory according to the connected user.

for example:

```
/manager/conf=superadmin, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
/manager/conf=admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN
/manager/conf=user, role: ROLE_USER
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Symfony doesn't check query string. In your case the best option would be to define a route path like this: `/manager/conf/{role}` and then configure access_control:

```
/manager/conf/superadmin, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
/manager/conf/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN
/manager/conf/user, role: ROLE_USER
```

Or depending how your configuration manager works, you could load a configuration using `$role` parameter that will be passed to your controller.

Another option is to use Voters (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) to verify if the user should be granted access to your resource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand what you mean. But I use FileManagerBundle (https://github.com/artgris/FileManagerBundle/blob/master/README.md)  and I can't redefine the route. By default is /manager/?conf=

Comment: Then according to the documentation you need to configure your own service that grants/denies access to a specific namespaces: https://github.com/artgris/FileManagerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/book/2-service-configuration.md

Comment: Thx you very much, i didn't saw this part of documentation ;)